# How does this regex pattern work

Tags: regex

I am learning regex and I am currently looking at this page http://regexone.com/example/0 I am following everything ok so far but I dont understand how this one works

```
^-?\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+(e\d+)?)?$
```

It matches the following text:

- 3.14529
- -255.34
- 128
- 1.9e10
- 123,34.00

And skips this one:

- 720p

The solution explains it like this

> For the above example, the expression '^-?\d+(,\d+)*(.\d+(e\d+)?)?$'
>   will match a string that starts with an optional negative sign, one or
>   more digits, optionally followed by a comma and more digits, followed
>   by an optional fractional component which consists of a period, one or
>   more digits, and another optional component, the exponent followed by
>   more digits.

The * is where I get confused. I read it like this:

```
^                 Start
-?                Optional Negative
\d+               One or more digits
(,\d+)*           Group-comma and one or more digits - the * confuses me here
(\.\d+(e\d+)?)?   Optional group of full stop, one or more digits, another optional group of e and 1 or more digits
```

As I said the * confuses me. I think it is something to do with Variable content but I dont understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is simply a quantifier that states: 'match 0 or more of the previous match', in this case `(,\d+)`.

In this case, it would match something like:

```
,123,123,123,63,345,345,346,3245235,234  (of any length but similar pattern)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Kk9Mnq-g5Td5NfXH)

Comment: Ok so it makes it so it can recur, but only in that section am I right? Is it the * that makes it optional (0 or more) or is it one of the ? that does that bit?

Comment: @PierceMcGeough, Yes somewhat. The `?` is like `+` but it also allows zero matches. For example `(ab*)` would match `abbbb`, `ab` and also `a`. Hope that helps

Comment: Yes when trying myself (before looking at the solution) I used ? but it in turn included 720p which I was not looking to do

Comment: @PierceMcGeough, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

that means that `zero` or `more` times a group like this `,34` is allowed.

group like `,34` or `,666` is represented as `(,\d+)*`

so that it allows text 122,222,12 or 323,212,22